# If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: w="true" or w={value.toString()}

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I got this error while rendering:

> Warning: Received 'true' for a non-boolean attribute 'w'.
>   If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: w="true" or w={value.toString()}.

When I remove the code below my code the error disappears:

```
<div className="form-group">
  <div className="col-12">
    <label htmlFor="inputConfirmType">Type de confirmation</label>
    <select id="inputConfirmType" name="confirmType" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required>
      <option value=""w>Selectionner un type</option>
      <option value="Ecole">Ecole</option>
      <option value="Professeur">Professeur</option>
      <option value="Inspecteur">Inspecteur</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `w` in your code.

Answer (score 9):

There's a loose "w" floating around in one of your select options:

```
<option value=""w>Selectionner un type</option>
```

That's the culprit. It should be:

```
<option value="">Selectionner un type</option>
```

Comment: And what if we really want the custom attribute, like : value="" fill> (to pass it as a React prop)?

Answer (score 2):

I have only encountered this error when there is an unnecessary character mostly a typo in this case the unnecessary "w" and when I had my issue got this error

*Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `c`.*
*If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: c="true" or c={value.toString()}.
at form
at div*

meaning the undeclared "c" was inside a div in my form and is considered `true` though it's not a type boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You missed writing between the double quote "":

```
<option value=""w>Selectionner un type</option>
```

should be:

```
<option value="w">Selectionner un type</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple use case of this kind of issue, just incase anyone faces such.
see the screenshot below of the error.
[image: error_message]

To solve this issue, read through the error, in my case you can see the screenshot points to the Footer section, look through the footer and remove the extra character "s" causing the issue.

[image: Footer Image]